# When using angular web components, how can i bundle in a web worker?

Tags: javascript, angular, web-component, web-worker

I have a project and we use Angular web components to include the functionality in another
non-angular project. Fine this works well.

I would like to use a web worker. Again, this is fine, and works when used in a regular angular app.

When I build the app to use it as a component, the worker file is outputted to separate file called 33.js (will this always be names 33.js? I suspect not, though thus far it has always been).

This name is resolved in the complied js.
I use an npm script to concatenate the output files to one file, for easy distribution.

When i run my component, in the non-angular project page, it will try to load the 33.js file. However:

1. The file path of 33.js is expected to be local to the page, which it wouldn't be, it would be in a scripts folder.
2. The file wouldn't be there (the scripts folder), as I haven't moved it.

*How can I bundle this file along with my main web component either by setting the path and filename, or better yet in the main component file. (or some other magical way)*

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try using [inline workers](https://web.dev/workers-basics/#inline-workers)? I'm facing the same problem, however my worker uses external scripts and I can't figure out how to put it all together. Have you found a solution? Also, I've just started checking out the [ngx-build-plus package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-build-plus), maybe it can lead to something

Comment: @koraljko The inline workers looks like it might be worth a try. I do remember trying some things *like* this, but can't remember if I did this specifically.

I never found solution, and time constraints simply meant I had to abandon the WebWorker. I will keep digging in the future though, as it would be beneficial. I will update here if/when i get a chance to investigate the inline worker.

Comment: @Dude0001 no, i still haven't investigated. But I still intend to find out - my code is still commented :)